# Is it possible to search the SESSIONs across multiple visitors

Tags: php, session

A SESSION is created for each website visitor.

Some visitors have `$_SESSION['reference'] = "foo"` others have `$_SESSION['reference'] = "bar"`.

`$number_of_visitors = count(scandir(ini_get("session.save_path")));` counts the number of sessions but does not test for `'reference' = "foo"`.

`$number_of_foo_visitors = count($_SESSION['foo']);` only counts 1 (ie. myself) because it is limited to only that visitor's session data. What it does not count is all current sessions where `'reference' = "foo"`

Is it possible to count across all visitors SESSIONs where `$_SESSION['reference'] = "foo"`?

Comment: not without opening every session, unserializing the data, and checking the value. This would kill your site for performance and is completely horrible as well.

Comment: If you need to track information about your visitors, writing a script that reads all their session data isn't a very secure approach

Comment: Webservers are designed to only be able to present the user with his own session, so no.

Comment: It should be noted that sharing data between users is exactly what databases are for.

Comment: In my searching this question I didn't find anything saying it could not be done but also no information as to how. The lack of information on "How to" is obvious... Don't try it!! I had already abandoned this in favor of updating a MySQL table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not (without a lot of work and breaking things). You should add this data to a database or file in order to reference it. $_SESSION is intended only to retrieve the current session not the sessions for others.